# How to smooth mouse movement of pyautogui?

Tags: python, bezier, pyautogui

I am trying to move the mouse continuously with pyautogui so, I used a loop and moveTo function of pyautogui to move the mouse continuously to random points but I don't know to smooth the paths so that they don't look like intersecting lines. I found out that I can use Bezier curves but I couldn't find any explanation on how to use that.

```
import pyautogui 
x_dim, y_dim = pyautogui.size()
for i in range(1,50):
    pyautogui.moveTo(random.randint(0, x_dim), random.randint(0, y_dim), duration = 0.25)
```

Also is there any function that allows us to restrict our mouse movement to an element on a website?

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues? (If not, did you remember to post an issue there, since they're the absolute highest authority when it comes to this question)